Conditional distribution of a function of two independent continuous random variables
Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent continuous random variables and let
$$
Z \equiv g(X, Y),
$$
where $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth. Is it true that the distribution of $Z$ given that $Y = y$ is the distribution of $g(X, y)$?
This assertion is used in Sheldon Ross: A First Course in Probability (10th edition, page 283, Example 5c) where the t-distribution $T$ is derived from the expression
$$
T = \sqrt{n} \frac{Z}{\sqrt{Y}},
$$
where $Z$ and $Y$ are independent, with $Z$ having a standard normal distribution and $Y$ having a chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. It is asserted that because of the independence of $Z$ and $Y$, it follows that the conditional distribution of $T$ given that $Y = y$ is the distribution of $\sqrt{n/y} \, Z$. I have no clue how to prove this though.

Can you clarify what you are looking for? What would it mean to prove that the conditional distribution of $T$ given that $Y=y$ is the distribution of $\sqrt{n/y}Z$?

In the book, they claim that because of the independence of $Z$ and $Y$, it follows that the conditional distribution of $T$ given that $Y= y$ is the distribution of $\sqrt{n/y} Z$, which is normal with mean 0 and variance $n/y$. Hence, the conditional density of $T$ given that $Y= y$ is $$f_{T|Y}(t|y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n / y}} e^{-t^2 y / 2 n}.$$

Isn't it so trivial that it doesn't need a formal proof? Given $Y=y$, we have $Z=g(X,y)$ and due to independence the conditioning on $Y$ takes no effect on $X$. The fact that $Z$ and $g(X,y)$ are the same thing implies they have the same distribution.
